# Is it better for performance to use boost::reversed than accessing back to front?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, reverse

Is it better for performance to use `boost::adaptors::reverse` to access elements in a vector in reversed order instead of the usual `v[i-1]`?

I.E.:

```
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4};
for (const auto& el : boost::adaptors::reverse(v))
  print(el);
```

vs

```
std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4};
for (size_t i = v.size(); i > 0; --i)
  print(v[i - 1]);
```

My logic would say that is not because reverse has to reverse the vector and then access it one by one and the usual way would load the vector piece in cache and then access the elements in reverse order. I guess that depending on the size of the vector one would be better than the other one, but I don't see why it would as a general rule.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but you can try benchmarking it. Also, std::vector already has a reverse iterator, so that boost adaptor is going to be redundant.

Comment: "reverse has to reverse the vector". No, it doesn't do that.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for for how the range for is implemented. It's personal opinion, but in the second case I prefer `for (size_t i = v.size(); i --> 0; )` and then you access `v.at(i)` in the loop body.

Comment: @Bathsheba good old "operator downto"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reverse has to reverse the vector

No, it's only an adaptor, it doesn't do anything to the vector. What it does is provide `begin` as the vector's `rbegin`, and `end` as the vector's `rend`. So these two pieces of code are more or less equivalent.